# Implementing a distributed grep

Tags: distributed-computing

I'm trying to implement a distributed grep. How can I access the log files from different systems? I know I need to use the network but I don't know whether you use ssh, telnet, or anything else? What information do I need to know about the machines I am going to connect to from my machine? I want to be able to connect to different Linux machines and read their log files and pipe it back to my machine.

Comment: it all depends on your use case, this question as it stands now is way too broad.

Comment: You could configure `rsyslogd`  to send the logs to a centralized server.

Answer (score 1):

Your system contains a number of Linux machine which produce log data(SERVERs), and one machine which you operate(CLIENT). Right?

Issue 1) file to be accessed.
 In general, log file is locked by a software which produce log data, because the software has to be able to write data into log file at any time.
To access the log file from other software, you need to prepare unlocked log data file.
Some modification of the software's setup ane/or the software(program) itself.

Issue 2) program to serve log files.
 To get log data from SERVER, each SERVERs have to run some server program.
For remote shell access, rshd (remote shell deamon) is needed. (ssh is combination of rsh and secure communication).
For FTP access, ftpd (file transfer protocol deamon) is needed.
The software to be needed is depend how CLIENT accesses SERVERs.

Issue 3) distribued grep.
 You use words 'distribued grep'. What do you mean by the words?
What are distribued in your 'distributed grep'?
Many senarios came in my mind.
a) Log files are distribued in SERVERs. All log data are collected to CLIENT, and grep program works for collected log data at CLIENT.
b) Log files are distribued in SERVERs. Grep function are implemented on each SERVERs also. CLIENT request to each SERVERs for getting the resule of grep applied to log data, and results are collected to CLIENT.
etc.
 What is your plan?

Issue 4) access to SERVERs. 
  Necessity of secure communication is depend on locations of machines and networks among them.
  If all machines are in a room/house, and networks among machines are not connected the Internet, secure communication is not necessary.
  If the data of log is top secret, you may need encript the data before send the data on the network.
  How is your log data important?

At very early stage of development, you should determing things described above.
This is my advice.